# git fails with "gnutls_handshake() failed"

Tags: git, ssl, openssl, gnutls

Yesterday I have set up a new server from a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 LTS image. I installed git-core in version 1.7.9.5. Now I get the following error by trying to clone an existing repository:

```
error: gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received. while accessing https://github.com/***/***/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I have read that the reason can be a wrong certificate but how can this happen when I am directly connected to the internet without any firewall/proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to check your .git/config file, and make sure that github has your public ssh key (located at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub or ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub). My .git/config file is shown below (username and repo should by relevant to you):

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/username/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: This is not the reason for this issue. I just wanted to clone a public repository without any need to push things, I just want to pull updates. But thanks for your input. BTW: Now it seems to work well :/.. A few weeks ago, it did not.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Glad it worked out somehow, though.